# Multiple input array is not working in for loop using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 3 input array fields whom I am calling by name using JS. When I call only one array input then its work as per loop, for example, if loop will run 3 times then it will show alert 3 times using below code

```
 function checkFluency() {
    var costPrice = document.getElementsByName('costPrice[]');
    var salePrice = document.getElementsByName('salePrice[]');
    var gst = document.getElementsByName('gst[]');
    for (var i = 0; i <costPrice.length; i++) {
        var costPrice_arr=costPrice[i];
        var salePrice_arr=salePrice[i];
        var gst_arr=gst[i];
        //var sale = salePrice_arr.value;
        var cost = costPrice_arr.value;
        //var gst = gst_arr.value;
      
      alert(cost);
        
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have commented 2 lines which contains value of array input. When I uncomment any of this line. then loop only run once. If loop need to run 3 times, then it will run only one time if I uncomment any of these 2 lines.

Because of this, I couldn't right my code further in JS. Not getting what causing loop to stop. Any idea please, why loop only works if I use only one array input field?

> update

It is showing in console `Type Error: salePrice_arr is undefined`. But it is defined same as "costPrice_arr"!

[image]

Comment: is the length of salePrice and gst also 3 or greater?
Please add the values of the array in the question as well.

Comment: Check the console, you probably get an error logged there

Comment: @manjish Yes, I am entering value in input fields myself. So its same. Besides, will this might cause loop to stop?

Comment: Can you include your HTML

Comment: `Not getting what causing loop to stop` - look in the browser console for errors.

Comment: First `var gst_arr=gst[i]` and then `gst = gst_arr.value`? That doesn't seem right. Why are you doing that? Your issue is probably that you overwrite `gst` with `undefined` or something which causes an exception on the second iteration at `gst[i]`.

Comment: @Lennholm It says this in console `product:664 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at checkFluency (product:257)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (product:439)` @james . On line 257, there is nothing related to this JS.  And my codeigniter view files don't have only 300 around lines, so don't know why its targetting 439 lines.

Comment: @Rishabh Obviously at least one of your variables in the loop becomes `undefined`. Troubleshoot by using breakpoints and/or `console.log()` statements to check the state of your variables at various points of the execution of the loop.

Comment: @Lennholm It is showing `Type Error: salePrice_arr is undefined`. But is it defined same as `costPrice_arr`. And costPrice_arr is showing result fine. Any idea?

Comment: @Rishabh definitely the length of costPrice and salePrice is not the same. Looks like your costPrice.length > salePrice.length . So in the loop for some value of  ** i ** the salePrice_arr is undefined because the value doesn't exist at that index in the salePrice. Do console the values.

Comment: Yeah, I tried the above comment, that was the same error I am getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `var gst = gst_arr.value;` to `var gst_new = gst_arr.value;`. Also, you mispelled `salePrice_arr.value;`. Change it to `salePrice_ar.value;`

Here:

```js
function checkFluency() {
  var costPrice = document.getElementsByName('costPrice[]');
  var salePrice = document.getElementsByName('salePrice[]');
  var gst = document.getElementsByName('gst[]');

  for (var i = 0; i < costPrice.length; i++) {

    var costPrice_arr = costPrice[i];
    var salePrice_ar = salePrice[i];
    var gst_arr = gst[i];
    var sale = salePrice_ar.value;
    var cost = costPrice_arr.value;
    var gst_new = gst_arr.value;

    alert(cost);

  }
}
```

```html
<input name="costPrice[]" value="1" />
<input name="salePrice[]" value="2" />
<input name="gst[]" value="3" />
<input name="costPrice[]" value="2" />
<input name="salePrice[]" value="4" />
<input name="gst[]" value="6" />
<input name="costPrice[]" value="3" />
<input name="salePrice[]" value="6" />
<input name="gst[]" value="9" />

<button onclick="checkFluency()">Check</button>
```

The case for your image is something like this:

```js
function checkFluency() {
  var costPrice = document.getElementsByName('costPrice[]');
  var salePrice = document.getElementsByName('salePrice[]');
  var gst = document.getElementsByName('gst[]');

  for (var i = 0; i < costPrice.length; i++) {
    var salePrice_arr = 0;
    var gst_arr = 0;

    salePrice_arr = salePrice[i];
    var costPrice_arr = costPrice[i];
    gst_arr = gst[i];
    var sale_new = salePrice_arr.value;
    var cost = costPrice_arr.value;
    var gst_new = gst_arr.value;

    alert(cost);

  }
}
```

```html
<input name="costPrice[]" value="1" />
<input name="salePrice[]" value="2" />
<input name="gst[]" value="3" />
<input name="costPrice[]" value="2" />
<input name="salePrice[]" value="4" />
<input name="gst[]" value="6" />
<input name="costPrice[]" value="3" />
<input name="salePrice[]" value="6" />
<input name="gst[]" value="9" />
<!-- Extra -->
<input name="costPrice[]" value="3" />
<button onclick="checkFluency()">Check</button>
```

Comment: Can't believe, I copied same method as your but still it is not working. And yet your working in snippet!!

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Btw I updated the for loop, I changed `for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)` to for (var i = 0; i < costPrice.length; i++)

Comment: Same error, I added value attribute also but still didn't work. I don't know why it is happening.

Comment: From the image you're showing, it seems your declaring `var salePrice_arr=0;` but you're trying to access it with `salePrice_arr.value`. Change `salePrice_arr.value` to just `salePrice_arr`.

Comment: `var salePrice_arr=0;` I just did for testing. It was saying not defined, So I tried to initialize before assigning value to it just for testing.

Comment: Yes, but your assigning it by `salePrice_arr=salePrice[i];` which means `salePrice_arr` is already the value of the input. So `salePrice_arr.value` does not make sense.

Comment: if I don't use `salePrice_arr.value` then I get this error `[object HTMLInputElement]`. I searched and found we must use `.value` with var if value is being fetched from input field.

Comment: Your `costPrice[]` inputs are more than the `salePrice[]` inputs

Comment: I added a likely case for what might be happening on your code.

Comment: Very strange, last night your suggestion wasn't working but today when I try then it is working fine O_O Is JS is playing with me or my luck is teasing me, damn. It is working without even without value attribute now. Thanks a ton for the help and your time :)